# Text in corner of tikz rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I write some text in the bottom-right hand corner of a rectangle so that the text is as far to the right and down as possible without exceeding the bounds of the rectangle?

The rectangle is defined using `fit`, like so:

```
\node[draw=black,inner sep=2mm,thick,rectangle,fit=(a) (b)] {};
```

Comment: Do you need the text to be flowed, or are you using explicit `\\\`s?

Comment: I just need one line of equation text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While driving up from Wales to London, I realised that the `tabular` was redundant for the question as asked, and when I arrived, I found that @Caramdir had justly taken me to task. Here is a completely new answer, which addresses a bit more than the original question.

---

For a single line of text, all you need to do is align the **node**:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (a) {a};
\node at (5,5) (b) {b};
\node[draw=black,inner sep=2mm,thick,rectangle,fit=(a) (b)] (x) {};
\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=1pt] at (x.south east) 
    {$ H \Psi = \nabla \Psi $};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

For multiple lines, things get a bit more elephantine, though the next release of Tikz will have, I believe, constructs like `align=right` for text. Meanwhile, one way is to use a `tabular`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (a) {a};
\node at (5,5) (b) {b};
\node[draw=black,inner sep=0pt,thick,rectangle,fit=(a) (b)] (x) {};
\node[anchor=south east] at (x.south east) {%
    \begin{tabular}{r} 
    $ H \Psi = \nabla \Psi $\\
    $ J \Phi = \nabla \Phi $
    \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You may want to tweak the tabular parameters to alter the space between the right/bottom of the text 
and the corner of the rectangle...

Comment: Is there any reason for the `tabular` environment?

Comment: Only my stupidity. I'll fix it when I've finished dinner.

Comment: @Neil: hope you used the simpler one...

@Caramdir: I *kmew* there was a use for `tabular` in the multiline case. Was I right?